# Why do I have this error (program shut down for using 13 cpu seconds)

Tags: python, error-handling

I am still learning python, and I wrote a code that takes a list of numbers and adds the odd numbers.
If there are more than 5 odd numbers, add only the first 5 numbers, but if there isn't, add them all.
Here is the code

```
num_list = [422, 136, 524, 85, 96, 719, 85, 92, 10, 
17, 312, 542, 87, 23, 86, 191, 116, 35, 173, 45, 149, 
59, 84, 69, 113, 166]
odd_nums =list()
sum_odd = list () 
x, y, z = 0, 0, 0 
for i in num_list :
    if i%2 != 0 :
        odd_nums.append(i) 

if len(odd_nums) >5 :
    while y < 5 :
        sum_odd.append(y)
    z=sum(sum_odd) 
    print (z)

else :
    x=sum(odd_nums)
    print (x)
```

Comment: It seems that you are running your code on some online Python interpreter or submitted it to some site. In such a case there will be a time limit for the program to run. This is not an error message Python itself would give you. Please clarify in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your program gets stuck in

```
while y < 5:
     sum_odd.append(y)
```

because you initialized `y` to 0 and never change it, hence the condition `y < 5` is always true.